# can you help me draw this picture with tikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf

[image: tikz]

can you help me draw this picture with tikz? thank you so much!

Comment: @down-voters: **Please don't downvote below a score of -1, even if the question in its current form needs some improvement. A score of -1 is enough to show that the question needs work, anything below that is of no use.** Also, if you downvote or vote to close, please leave a comment explaining why you did so, but wait at least 24 hours after asking the OP for improvements to the question before voting to close.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can adjust the width, height, color and so on, hopefully the keys are self-explanatory, in any case they are well documented in the manual.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \path foreach \Y [evaluate=\Y as \Xmax using {int(3-\Y)}] in {0,...,3}
  {foreach \X in {-\Xmax,...,\Xmax}
  {(\X,\Y) node[cylinder,draw,fill=green!80!black,rotate=90,minimum
  width=4mm,minimum height=7mm]{}}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: that's great. Thank you so much.